Can I not pay the APCs in IOP? They offer only open-acess
I submitted my paper in IOP-MRX without knowing it only offers open-access. It went through peer review and got accepted. When I received the email for paying APCs, I requested a waiver from the editor. They declined my request, telling me nothing can be done. Meanwhile, the paper went through publishing, a license was issued and it got published. I have been receiving emails for payment, but I have requested a waiver multiple times and asked them to redact paper if any waiver cannot be granted as my last resort. They said redaction isn't possible at this stage either. What do I do? Please help.
I am concerned if they can take any legal action.

If you are concerned about potential legal problems, then you need to seek advice from a lawyer not random people on the Internet. Than you need to think what is more expensive: paying the fee or paying the lawyer...

Does this answer your question? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/201921/the-article-publishing-charge-of-775-was-not-settled-and-now-there-is-a-debt-co

It is hard for me to understand how you didn't know that IOP isn't exclusively open access. They are very clear about that.

When you say "redact", do you mean "retract"?

I am not a lawyer, but, yes, they can take some action. I think it unlikely that they would sue you, since the amounts are relatively small relative to the costs of litigation. But they could affect your credit rating negatively, which might make some things harder, like getting a credit card and such.
In some places Small Claims Court is used for recovery of modest amounts of money and failing to pay after a judgement against you can have legal repercussions as well.
I suggest that you find a way to pay the charge at this point, even borrowing funds to do so. They seem to have behaved honorably, given how they present themselves to the world. You would do best to behave accordingly.
Perhaps your own institution can help.
I doubt that it will have negative effects on your academic reputation, but you should understand the policies of any publisher that you submit to. This is just "due diligence". Sorry to be blunt.

Note that even in small claims court, lawyers need to be paid. That results in two effects. First, it makes it less likely that a suit will happen, but, if the rules permit lawyer's fees to be passed on to be passed on to an unsuccessful defendant, then the ultimate cost is greatly increased. That depends on local rules, of course, and they vary.

"Note that even in small claims court, lawyers need to be paid" - at least where I live, small claims court is specifically designed to not require lawyers, which is what makes it distinct from Big Claims Court. Of course you're still allowed to bring a lawyer, but the whole point is to allow the legal system to handle disputes too small for it to be worth paying lawyers.

@BryanKrause, yes, true for claims between individuals. But the company will, indeed, have lawyers and they get paid, probably handsomely. I don't, of course, know whether local rules permit the passing of litigating costs to the loser.
